# Quick Reply: NSURLSessionDataTask from "userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:"

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, background-process, nsurlsession

I have Remote Notifications set up successfully for my Messaging App and want to incorporate the "Quick Reply"-functionality of iOS, better known as `UNTextInputNotificationAction` of `UNUserNotificationCenter` now.

I added the Text Input Action to my incoming message notifications and it is working as expected.

My Problem lies in the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` function `userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:`.

No matter how I set up the `NSURLSessionDataTask` to `POST` the input response `userText` of `UNTextInputNotificationResponse`, the Request always times out. It does work fine when I am "Quick replying" to a notification received while the app is in the Foreground.

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {

    if ([response isKindOfClass:UNTextInputNotificationResponse.class]) {

        if ([response.actionIdentifier isEqualToString:@"REPLY_MESSAGE"]) {

            [ApiManager chatWithId:@"123456789abcdefg" postTextMessage:[(UNTextInputNotificationResponse *)response userText] completion:^(Message *message) {

                if (!message) {

                   NSLog(@"Sending failed");

                }

                completionHandler();
            }];
        }
    }

}
```

The Data Task within `ApiManager` is built atop a `[NSURLSession sharedSession]` - Note that this did not work, even after changing it to `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:` and implementing the needed Delegate methods.

The Log "Sending failed" can be seen through the Console, if I check the error of the DataTask, it shows a "Timeout" error.

I suspect I have something wrong with my background networking, but I cannot wrap my head around it, and nowhere I looked was an answer to be found. The documentation is very sparse here too.

Comment: It's odd that you get a timeout error. In the past when I've tried to start DataTasks from the background, I get an error specifying that only upload and download tasks are allowed to run in the background, but not data tasks. Try changing your data task to an upload task, see if there's any change.

Comment: @John Wickham: I tried with a background session and a upload task. Neither worked. I always get the timeout nevertheless.

Comment: That's very interesting. How long does it take before you get the timeout error? I believe the default timeout interval is 60 seconds.

Comment: @JohnWickham yeah 60 Seconds is Right

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling about this issue in the future: I was able to solve it by adding `content-available:1` to my push notification payload. I am still using a data task and a shared url session here. No delegate either, working with completion blocks, for anyone interested.

I initially did not think this would work, adding the content available flag actually had another reason, so it’s nice that this solves the initial problem I had. Why did I think this wouldn’t work? Easy, because the content available, if we believe the documentation, indicates to the app, that there is content available to download. There is a special application delegate method being called for specifically this situation:

`application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`

It is a nice side effect that the method which responds to user actions on notifications also gets more time to process.

Neat bonus: I also found out that, without adding the content-available flag, the quick reply would work from the Apple Watch, as, I guess, the OS allows the app to perform longer background operations when responding to a request from the Apple Watch.